# Brown mold on my reishi grow?

Tags: mushrooms

I'm growing a monotub of reishi. The tub is well colonised but it looks like there's a couple square inches where the reishi myc isn't growing and I noticed a small patch of brown eaten into the mycelium. 
I just cut it out with a sterilised spoon but is there anything chemical I can do to mold if it appears ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like a bacterial contamination. But Reishi is an odd bird and really aggressive. It would not surprise me to see it recover in that area. It might even be feeding on the bacteria.

Comment: Your absolutely right. I scraped a big area clean and it's already nearly grown over with reishi mycelium. I was worried that my disturbing the mold would spread it but it looks pretty good now.
If it does turn up again I would prefer some sort of spray that kills it without spreading it too much.
Next hurdle is fruiting. I want spores so I think conks, not antlers, is the way to go but not sure if I can create proper conditions.

Comment: ...and it might have been bacteria, it was hard to tell but it did look a bit fuzzy.

Comment: Boom, just got loads of green. With a white fluffy quality which looks like the stuff you get on oranges so maybe a penicillium mold ?

Comment: Bummer. This is typically what the green is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichoderma. Definitely want to get it out of your house with as little disturbance as possible.

Comment: Yeah. It would be good if I stuck it in the yard and it still came up with reishi conks. It's in a taped box with polyfil filters so it shouldn't be a contam threat. I think it got in when I opened it to peek.

Comment: I've found that it isn't mold at all, it's just dried up reishi mycelium. I threw out a really nice grow to :-(

Comment: That's a bummer. Are you saying the green you described was reishi mycelium? How'd you make the determination?